# How to pass data from one react component to other react component when clicking on <Link tag

Tags: reactjs

How to pass data from one react component to other react component when clicking on

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "title": "XYZ Title",
  "body": "www.xyz.com sample hits",
  "comments": [
   {
    "id": 1,
    "postId": 1,
    "name": null,
    "email": "abc@cc.com",
    "body": "very simple body"
   }
 ]
}
]
```

I have two JSX pages, one for posts and second JSX page for comments. When clicking on post need to navigate the comments page for this post.See below code snippet.
Posts.jsx

```
<tbody>
{posts.map((post) => (
<tr key={post.id}>
<td>
<Link
to={`/posts/${post.id}`}
>
{post.title}
</Link>
</td>
<td>{post.body}</td>
```

How can we get and iterate relevant comments data for give post id (when clicking on link of post id). How to pass comments data from posts.jsx to comments.jsx when clicking on post.id of post to comments.jsx

Comments.jsx

```
 <tbody>
{comments.map((comment) => (
<tr key={comment.id}>
<td>{comment.name}</td>
<td>{comment.email}</td>
<td>{comment.body}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data something like this :

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: `/posts/${post.id}`,
  state: post // <---- Pass post object here
}}>{post.title}</Link>
```

---

And get access inside component via `location` :

```
// class based component
const post_data = this.props.location.state; // <--- get access to post object
```

```
// for functional based component
let location = useLocation()
const post_data = location.state;
```

Comment: Thanks your response and your solution works. Great !

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props in `<Link to={{pathname: something, props: something}} />`
and on target component use `props.location.state` through `useLocation() hook` or `withRouter HOC`.
Additionally, you can pass props on URL to reload don't lost them.